# MSVC 2013 ambiguous symbol

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

MSVC 2013 sees my local (to a namespace) `typedef` of `uint32_t` with the global definition by `stdint.h`  Is there any way get around this?

Basically, my code is:

```
#include <stdint.h>

namespace MyNamespace {
    typedef uint32_t uint32_t;
}
```

And this code won't compile when I include stuff that uses `uint32_t` from the global namespace defined in `stdint.h`.

GCC and Clang handle this perfectly.

I've tried using `using` rather than `typedef`, defining it the exact same  way `stdint.h` defines it, nothing I've tried convinces MSVC to resolve the symbol properly.

Basically I'm stuck, and I can't really change external interface (e.g. rename `MyNamespace::uint32_t` to something unique)

Comment: try using ::uint32_t

Comment: works on msvc2017

Comment: I tried :(  Specifically, `typedef ::uint32_t uint32_t`.  No dice.

Comment: @rex The purchase order for MSVC 2017 is making its way through our bureaucracy right now, but until it's through, MSVC 2013 is all I got.  Good to know it works though. (there are a bunch of bugs in MSVC 2013, especially with SFINAE, that I'm waiting on MSVC 2017 to fix)

Comment: `typedef uint32_t uint32_t;` <-- you are missing `;` at the end.

Comment: @VTT Oops, typo, I updated the question.